# rsync brace expansion insight

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, rsync, copy

I want to sync my ubuntu 14.04 installation with a directory in an external disk.

Actually I booted up from an expansion drive and I want to make a partial copy of my ubuntu 14.04 distro in the internal drive which I mounted on `/media/kenn/c2d1b866/`

The destination directory mounted on `/mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5`

I tried many combinations of **rsync** command such as

```
sudo rsync -avr /media/kenn/c2d1b866/{bin/,sbin/,usr/,opt/,lib/,var/,etc/,srv/,libx32/,lib64/,run/,boot/,proc/,sys/,dev/} /mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5

sudo rsync -avr /media/kenn/c2d1b866/{bin/,sbin/,usr/,opt/,lib/,var/,etc/,srv/,libx32/,lib64/,run/,boot/,proc/,sys/,dev/} /mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5/

sudo rsync -avr /media/kenn/c2d1b866/{"bin/","sbin/","usr/","opt/","lib/","var/","etc/","srv/","libx32/","lib64/","run/","boot/","proc/","sys/","dev/"} /mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5
```

and many other, but I failed, because brace expansion doesn't work as I expected. They copy all files inside brace directories into `/mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5` , I mean root directories not created in `backup_14.04.5`

How can I copy those `bin/,sbin/,usr/,opt/,lib/,var/,etc/,srv/,libx32/,lib64/,run/,boot/,proc/,sys/,dev/`

in `/media/kenn/c2d1b866/` to `/mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5` ?

Comment: You didn't say what happened with your tries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They copy all files inside brace directories into `/mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5`

That's the `rsync` behaviour when the source path has a trailing slash `/`.
From [`man rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rsync.1.html):

```
A  trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating
an additional directory level at the destination.  You can think  of  a
trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory"
as opposed to "copy the directory by  name",  but  in  both  cases  the
attributes   of   the  containing  directory  are  transferred  to  the
containing directory on the destination.
```

To copy the directories, omit that `/`:

```
sudo rsync -avr /media/kenn/c2d1b866/{bin,sbin,usr,opt,lib,var,etc,srv,libx32,lib64,run,boot,proc,sys,dev} /mnt/RESTORE/backup_14.04.5
```